# Batch move of many items between keychains without bother

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keychain, keychain-access

If I move 30 items from one keychain to another, I have to enter the same password 30-32 times, once for each item moved.

Can I avoid this?  On OSX 10.6 Server, using Keychain Access.

Comment: Googling around it seems like it might be possible to use applescript for this. However the Keychain scripting additions was removed from 10.7, so if you've updated then you'll have to copy that file from a pre Lion install. The base issue here is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah! Found this OS X hint: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101225081151172

Simply set a **blank password** for the keychain you're copying **from**. Keychain Access will complain that it's not good enough, unless you **press command** while clicking OK.

Then you'll be able to hammer "Allow" 100 times, which is a lot faster than typing your password 100 times.

It's not a nice solution, and perhaps a bit questionable security-wise, but it saves a lot of time.

Comment: I have to test this, but I'll accept it since several people have said it works for them.   The Mac World article says it's the destination keychain that needs blanking.  I think the security issue is not serious, provided a little care and awareness.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Actually the hint itself is wrong — read the comments by GDmac (who also submitted the hint). It's the password of the source keychain that's requested each time and is supposed to be blank.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like this solution, but it's better than nothing and worked got the job done.

Comment: I had 1000 keys, and this workaround helped

Comment: You have to make sure you change the password from the Edit menu and not from right-clicking on the keychain.

Comment: This workaround doesn't speed up the process in MacOS Sierra.

Comment: It did in High Sierra :-) Still useful in 2018.

Answer (score -1):

Just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+click the desired items and drag them to the desired keychain. If it still is asking for multiple passwords, I suggest copying the password to your clipboard and pasting into the password field.

Comment: That password entry box doesn't allow pasting.